# Google sheets. Custom script to move random value from on column to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like a custom script that can move a random value from one column to another

Example:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Can this somehow achieved?

Comment: Yes. Stackoverflow is a programmer's question and answer site. We do not accept free code requests. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/ for the type of questions, you're expected to ask here.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Do you have a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                              .getSheetByName(`MY_SHEET_NAME`)

  const colAValues = sheet.getRange(`A2:A`)
                          .getDisplayValues()
                          .filter(String)

  const colBValues = sheet.getRange(`B2:B`)
                          .getDisplayValues()
                          .filter(String)
  
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colAValues.length)
  const randomValue = colAValues.splice(colAValues.indexOf(randomIndex), 1)
  colBValues.push(randomValue)

  sheet.getRange(`A:B`).clearContent()
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, colAValues.length, 1).setValues(colAValues)
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, colBValues.length, 1).setValues(colBValues)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Random Move

```
function randomMove() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let col1 = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
  let col2 = sh.getRange(2, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
  let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * col1.length);
  let v = col1[idx];
  if (col1[idx]) {
    col2.push(col1[idx]);
    col1.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  if (col1.length || col2.length) {
    sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).clearContent();
  }
  if (col1.length) {
    sh.getRange(2, 1, col1.length, 1).setValues(col1.sort((a, b) => a - b).map(e => [e]));
  }
  if (col2.length) {
    sh.getRange(2, 2, col2.length, 1).setValues(col2.sort((a, b) => a - b).map(e => [e]));
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]